# Help with StandardSetController Test with redirect

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, list-view, standardsetcontroller

I have a visualforce page that grabs the ids from a list view of the selected records. Then redirects to lightning component. I'm having trouble with my test class. I'm not able to get the assertions to pass on lines 25 and 26. I'm not able to get the controller to pass the list variable to the constructor. Here is my code so far. Thanks in advance for taking a look at it.

```java
@isTest
public class VFC_ProcessAccRecordsTest {
    @isTest
    static void testVFC_ProcessAccRecords() {
        // Create test data
        List<sdv_housing_request__c> houseList = new List<sdv_housing_request__c>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            houseList.add(new sdv_housing_request__c(sdvhr_email__c = 'test+'+i+'@testerson.edu'));
        }
        insert houseList;
        
        // Create a set of Ids to pass to the constructor
        Set<Id> houseIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (sdv_housing_request__c house : houseList) {
            houseIds.add(house.Id);
        }  
        // Create a StandardSetController and pass it to the constructor
        ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(houseList);
        VFC_ProcessAccRecords  controller = new VFC_ProcessAccRecords (standardController);
        system.debug(houselist.size());
        system.debug(controller.houseList.size());
        system.debug(houseIds);
        system.debug(controller.houseIds);
        // Ensure the constructor sets the houseList and houseIds correctly
        System.assertEquals(houseList.size(), controller.houseList.size());
        System.assertEquals(houseIds, controller.houseIds);
        
        // Test the redirectToLC method
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pgRef = controller.redirectToLC();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Ensure the PageReference is correct and has the expected parameters
        String expectedUrl = '/lightning/cmp/c__HousingCard?c__listofhousing=';
        for (Id houseId : houseIds) {
            expectedUrl += houseId + ',';
        }
        expectedUrl = expectedUrl.removeEnd(','); // Remove the trailing comma
        System.assertEquals(expectedUrl, pgRef.getUrl());
        //System.assertTrue(pgRef.isRedirect());
    }
}
```

```java
public class VFC_ProcessAccRecords {
    public List <sdv_housing_request__c> houseList {get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    public Set <Id> houseIds = new Set <Id>();

    // Constructor
    public VFC_ProcessAccRecords( ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController ) {
        this.standardController = standardController;
        houseList = new List<sdv_housing_request__c>();
        
        for (sdv_housing_request__c house : ( List<sdv_housing_request__c>)standardController.getSelected()){ 
            system.debug(house);
            
            houseIds.add(house.Id);
            system.debug(houseIds);
        }
    }

    public PageReference redirectToLC(){
        String returnUrl = '/lightning/cmp/c__HousingCard?c__listofhousing='+houseIds;
        PageReference pgReturnPage = new PageReference(returnUrl);
        pgReturnPage.setRedirect(true);
        return pgReturnPage;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I think it's going to be hard for anyone to provide help until you [edit] your question to include the code for `VFC_ProcessAccRecords`. Also, quick tip on formatting. For code, you either need to have 3 back-ticks `\`\`\`` on their own lines both above and below your code, or start every line of code with at least 4 spaces (which you can do by highlighting your code, then clicking the `{}` button).

Comment: Thanks Derek. I should of known to do that.  I posted the actual code below.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for (sdv_housing_request__c house : 
     ( List<sdv_housing_request__c>)standardController.getSelected()){
   ..
}
```

is invoking the `getSelected` method on the `standardSetController` object. But your testmethod never uses

```
 setSelected(SObject[] selectedRecords)
```

to give `getSelected()` something to return.  [StandardSetController method Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm#apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_setSelected). Just passing in a list of objects to the constructor only provides something for the standardSetController method `getRecords()` to return; not `getSelected()`.

So, in your testmethod

```
// Create a StandardSetController and pass it to the constructor
ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(houseList);
standardController.setSelected(houseList);  // <== add this line
```

***Side note***

I'd rename the variable `standardController` to `standardSetController` to avoid confusion with true `standardControllers` that operate on only a single record.

Comment: OP also needs to put data into `houseList` (right now, only `houseIds` is having data added to it)